# Validate broken copy paste user input

Tags: php, validation, input, utf-8

I'm looking for a **php function or library or suggestions** that can validate broken form input value when customer copy & pastes broken utf8 string.

Scenario:

1. Customer is asked to enter street name in
2. He opens **third party** broken page where he is storing address
3. Copies broken utf8 string (see examples)
4. Paste this string in input field and clicks Submit

So on server side, I'm receiving "correct" valid utf8 value.

Is there a way to catch this some how so I could catch it and show error message?

Test examples:

- "Atâ€™s â€˜em"
- "Bo�kowski"

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: You can use preg_match to validate if the input is valid or not ! you can for example compare it against letters and numbers like : a-z A-Z 0-9 :)

Comment: If they're *actually* pasting the word "Atâ€™s â€˜em" then they're actually pasting the word "Atâ€™s â€˜em" (just as I'm doing here right now). Nothing's "broken" per se, it's just not really the characters you want there (though I *do* want them here in this comment). So… that's a bit of a problem, since there's no obvious *correct* answer. When *is* something broken, when *isn't* it…?

Comment: @deceze Exactly! Any advice on what way I should look for a way of catching it? I can try to predict everything I think is wrong case by case. But that will take forever.

Comment: The second case, pasting a � character, is broken beyond repair, the original character is *gone for good.* In the first case you can convert from UTF-8 to Latin-1 (or so) and interpret the result as UTF-8 again; you could try doing that automatically, perhaps recursively, until you start noticing that characters are being discarded (because they can't be represented in Latin-1), at which point you have reached the end of the conversion chain. Really though, a human needs to decide; perhaps pop up a message "This looks like mojibake", then present some guesses and let the user pick.

Comment: @deceze Thank you a lot for input! This is really helpfull. So I could validate exactly that.. strpos($value, "�") and if something found show error message.

Comment: @Lexi changed my question so it passes your hardcode scrutiny.

Comment: @wormhit hard code scrunity? I literally copied and pasted from the StackOverflow guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is no generic way of figuring out if value is wrong, I ended up matching regexp [A-Za-z0-9\ -.,] and showing warning message to user if not matched.

(suggested by @soheyl)

Answer (score 0):

At first a `UTF-8` string can't be broken. The string can have non utf-8 characters what make it seems like it's 'broken', while it is just a different encoding.

PHP has a function to check what kind of encoding is used for a given string:

```
string mb_detect_encoding ( string $str [, mixed $encoding_list = mb_detect_order() [, bool $strict = false ]] )
```

source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php.

But it only checks in what kind of encoding the given string is, so you can only check if the right encoding is used.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but in this case it will always be UTF-8, because it comes from valid utf8 encoded site.